# Tool to run same key strokes on multiple unix machines

Tags: linux, unix

I want to run the same commands on multiple machines, I know I can do this using ssh scripting or things like clusterssh, however I don't want to install anything on the server. (Don't have the rights)

What I want is to just clone the keystrokes across multiple machines e.g. run cat /etc/oratab on one window and same is run on multiple windows e.g. in putty, is there a tool to do that from a windows client.

Answer (score 0):

well - we do that in our place using terminator :

I have written an addon for terminator called termssh

https://github.com/vahidhedayati/termssh

using termssh which calls terminator you can issue something like

```
termssh -r -g -w 8 -n "my_short_name" -s "apache01[a-z]gw"

This will 
-r  recreate layout - no need if already done
-g group so all commands are repeated across all sessions
-w = windows per console so 8 then another 8 in next tab and so on 
-n = name for the sessions
-s = server search pattern
```

-s (apache|email)01[a-z]

where the new pattern above would look for apache01a..z as well as email01a..z if found then connects to them

forgot to add this may be another useful feature

```
    termssh -r -g -w 8  -x 2 -n "my_short_name" -s "apache01[a-z]gw"


-x = two connections per host found and 2 individual groups

so :
connection 1 to apach01agw will be part of group1 
connection 1 to apach01bgw will be part of group1 
connection 2 to apach01agw will be part of group2 
connection 2 to apach01bgw will be part of group2
```